# htaccess to Allow Downloads from Specific User agent and HTTP Referrer

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, hosting, apache-2.4

i want to allow some files to be downloaded if only the user agent or referrer match the following

These are the user agents *uTorrent* *Bittorrent* *Transmission*

This is the http referrer www.niresh12495.com

I'm trying the following code but shows Error 500

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(*uTorrent*|*BitTorrent*|*Transmission*) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://niresh12495.com/.*$      [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://niresh12495.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.niresh12495.com/.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.niresh12495.com$  [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^*\.(dmg|torrent|pkg|rar|exe|zip|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|bmp|mp3|flv|swf|png|css|pdf|mpg|mp4|mov|wav|wmv|swf|css|js|iso)$ http://www.niresh12495.com [R,F,NC]
```

Where am i wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems.

1. There are syntax errors in your regular expressions.  You're using `*` like a shell wildcard character, but in regexes it has a different meaning:  it only modifies another character, to mean "0 or more occurrences of".  What you probably want is `.*`, meaning "0 or more occurrence of any character".  But you don't even need that, if you remove the start anchor tag `^`.
2. Your last RewriteCond ends with an `OR` flag, which is probably invalid since no other RewriteCond follows it.
3. I think your conditional logic is wrong.  You currently have

> not (uTorrent or BitTorrent or Transmission) OR not niresh12495.com OR not www,.niresh12495.com

but I think you want

> not (uTorrent or BitTorrent or Transmission) AND not niresh12495.com AND not www.niresh12495.com

So I think you want something more like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(uTorrent|BitTorrent|Transmission) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.|)niresh12495.com(/|$) [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(dmg|torrent|pkg|rar|exe|zip|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|bmp|mp3|flv|swf|png|css|pdf|mpg|mp4|mov|wav|wmv|swf|css|js|iso)$ http://www.niresh12495.com [R,F,NC]
```

Comment: hi @andrew-schulman thanks for the answer but the problem is user agents they actually vary
uTorrent/12345
BitTorrent/1462
Transmission/SomeNumericValue
How can i solve this ?

Comment: The expression `(uTorrent|BitTorrent|Transmission)` isn't anchored, so it matches any of the strings uTorrent, BitTorrent, or Transmission if they appear anywhere in the string.  So it matches any of the cases you mentioned.