# Block Wildcard User-agent

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, rewritecond

how can i write rewrite condition for wildcard user agents

here is the code I'm trying but doesnt work

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !*uTorrent* [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !*BitTorrent* [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !*Transmission* [NC]
```

The problem is user agents are  in this format

```
uTorrent/12345
Bittorrent/2456
Transmission/"SomeRandomNumbers"
```

How can i write a proper (RewriteCond) Rewrite Condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [htaccess to Allow Downloads from Specific User agent and HTTP Referrer](https://serverfault.com/questions/580547/htaccess-to-allow-downloads-from-specific-user-agent-and-http-referrer), I already explained that (1) Your regular expressions are invalid, because you're misusing the `*` character (hint: it's not a wildcard), and (2) the regexes will work as you intend if you just remove the `*`s.

You should familiarize yourself with regular expressions.  The [mod_rewrite introduction to regular expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks :) Andrew
i work with bash so i'll learn regex too :)